# Sending data from Node script to Python on-the-fly

Tags: python, node.js, raspberry-pi

I'm doing a project with RPi and I want to send data from a node script to a python script and vice-versa on-the-fly. Using `spawn` method, I could run the script but that would create a new process every time I want to send the data and that would create a lot of lag.

Instead, I want both of them to run in infinite loops and call only those functions which have a change in data. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you need to pass data between the processes, or only trigger the other?

Comment: Yes, I need to pass data as well. I tried to bridge both the codes with help pf stdin and stdout streams but that's resulting in unexpected behaviors

Comment: So I think that running simple http servers on both python and node.js sides, and communicating with post requests for passing data might work for your use case.